# How know if user is visitor or logged and logged member username? in drupal 8

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I  having Drupal Experience last two month my requirement is  to Display Welcome with its Username  On Form Title it is possible to  get its name?
I have tried to found from google but not succeed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this link, you have explanation how to grab user object and its properties: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/184498/how-do-i-get-the-user-id-for-the-currently-logged-in-user

Comment: thanks for giving me kind of information.there is not drupal 8 question easily found